# How can i insert a url with PHP into ORACLE?

Tags: php, oracle

i'm using php to insert **URLs** into oracle.

i'm having a problem inserting urls in this format in the column ENDPOINT : http://lx2939:37080/Cougar/prod/api

it's saved in this format in the database:  http://lx2939?/Cougar/prod/api

This is the PHP code i'm using

```
$query = "INSERT INTO RECENTTESTS 
                (EMAIL, FILENAME, SOR, RECIPIENTS, LAUNCHALL, 
                ENDPOINT, ORGOID, ASSOCIATEOID, ROLECODE, REALM, CONSUMERAPPOID) 
        VALUES ('" . $email . "', '" . $fileNameInput . "', '" . $sor . "',
                '" . $recipients . "', '" . $launchAll . "','" . $endpoint . "',
                '" . $orgOID . "','" . $associateOID . "','" . $rolecode . "',
                '" . $realm . "','" . $consumeOID . "')";
$stid = oci_parse($conn, $query);
oci_execute($stid);
```

Could you please help me with this issue?

PS : When i execute the query directly into oracle it works as expected

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Comment: HINT: [`echo oci_error($conn);`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-error.php)

Comment: Seeing how `:37080` apparently got replaced by a `?`, I am guessing the query parser thinks this was placeholder syntax.

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). If you used a parepared parameterised query it would probably solve this issue as we as the SQL Injections issue

Answer (score 2):

You could fix 2 issues in one here.

Using a prepared parameterised query would almost definitely fix the issue you are having with the conversion of `:37080` to a `?` and also remove the likely [SQL Injection Issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174) in your code

```
$query = "INSERT INTO RECENTTESTS 
                (EMAIL, FILENAME, SOR, RECIPIENTS, LAUNCHALL, 
                ENDPOINT, ORGOID, ASSOCIATEOID, ROLECODE, REALM, CONSUMERAPPOID) 
        VALUES (:EMAIL, :FILENAME, :SOR, :RECIPIENTS, :LAUNCHALL, 
                :ENDPOINT, :ORGOID, :ASSOCIATEOID, :ROLECODE, :REALM, 
                :CONSUMERAPPOID)";

$stid = oci_parse($conn, $query);

oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":EMAIL", $email);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":FILENAME", $fileNameInput);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":SOR", $sor);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":RECIPIENTS", $recipients);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":LAUNCHALL", $launchAll);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":ENDPOINT", $endpoint);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":ORGOID", $orgOID);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":ASSOCIATEOID", $associateOID);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":ROLECODE", $rolecode);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":REALM", $realm);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":CONSUMERAPPOID", $consumeOID);

oci_execute($stid);
```

> You may also find it useful to read a little about catching and processing errors https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/appdev.112/e18555/ch_seven_error.htm#TDPPH165

Comment: It works fine this way, appreciated !